# How does Initialization on demand holder Idiom ensures only "single" instance is created ever?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I went through the wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom to understand Initialization on demand holder Idiom for Singleton pattern, though the wiki mentions how it's thread safe, it doesn't say how this actually ensures only one instance is created ever, i.e if in two different classes `Something.getInstance()` is called how do they have the same object ?

I am new to Java, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "only one instance ever created"? You mean to create a class of which you can only create one single instance? google "java Singleton", you should find plenty of texts explaining the concept.

Comment: @Stultuske yes, I have edited the question, making it more clear, my doubt is how Initialization on demand holder Idiom actually implements singleton pattern, i.e  if in two different places Something.getInstance() is called how do they have the same object ?

Comment: do you know what the keyword 'static' does? Only one instance is created, and that is returned each time the getInstance method is called. You should start at the beginning. get a decent textbook and start at the beginning. don't skip chapters because they seem "easy" or "boring", and work yourself through it.

Comment: Yes, I am new to Java, ramped up the basics. But my doubt is, say in different places `Something.getInstance()` is called, will the statement `static final Something INSTANCE = new Something();` be executed twice or only the first time, and the value of `INSTANCE` will be cached for further use ? Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: No, it will not. You should really read up on the basics, in this instance, the concept of static and how it works. If you don't understand that, you won't understand how a singleton works.

Comment: I agree, I have read from various sources before posting this, I am aware that static variables are initialized only once i.e. at the start of execution. But unable to relate with this context of static variable under a static class, would be really great if you could explain that part ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242864/discussion-between-ajay-sabarish-and-stultuske).

Answer (score 1):

Basic pattern for a singleton:

```
//final so it can't be extended, not needed, but I like it for security
public final class MySingleton {
    //Private so no other class can access it directly
    //static so it stays resident in memory
    //final so it can't be nulled out or reassigned;
    //The constructor is called when the class is loaded.
    private static final MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();

    //The constructor is private so no more instances can be created
    private MySingleton() {
    }

    public static final MySingleton getInstance() {
       return instance;
    }

    //Alternatively, you could have the instance initialized to null
    //and have creation when getInstance() is called
    public static final MySingleton getIntance() {
        synchronized(instance) {
           if (instance == null) {
               instance = new MySingleton();
           }
           return instance
        }
}
```